# How to get system Android emoji drawable by unicode character?

Tags: android, unicode, emoji

I want to implement an android emoji keyboard just using emoji unicode array, without any extra res.

So for the emoji unicode character, I need to get the drawable from android system, if the system doesn't support the charactor, I just ignore this character.

After some basic research,

- emojicon, `https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon`
- emojicon, `https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon`

These implements all use self made resources.

use TextView `setText`, `tv.setText("\u263A");` TextView can show the resource, but how can I get the resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the problem-  the system doesn't determine what characters can be displayed.  The font does.  The font needs to define how to draw every character it will display.  That's why you'll see boxes or ? for missing characters-  that's the font's default render.  There is no method on Android to test if a character will display in a given font (although it would be really nice).  And since there's no way to know what font the EditText is using, there's no way to know if a given character is supported.  Your best bet is to limit yourself to characters defined in the default Android System font.  But even then you're assuming the OEM didn't use a different default font, the user hasn't overridden it, and the app hasn't overridden it.  Basically, you're forced to guess and hope.

Comment: Do you have an idea what the OEMs typically do, i.e. is there a good chance to get the original Android emoji (instead of some OEM stuff) by explicitly requesting the droid sans font?

Comment: If its installed on the device, yes.  Or you can put it in your APK (you can load a font from assets) if you're ok with the extra space being taken up.

Comment: Thanks! I plan to use images as a fallback for Android < 4.4 (I think color fonts wouldn't work there). So I guess I could check for Droid Sans being available and fall back to images if not in Android >= 4.4. My main concern is that some OEMs just replace the Emoji with their own "interpretation" of what they should look like inside Droid Sans, and I have no simple way of detecting this (other than comparing the rendering of a sample to the stored image). I'd like to use the font-based Emoji if available because they scale better (up to a point, where they just disappear -- another story...